# ngif how to give multiple conditions

Tags: angular, typescript

This is html file

```
<div class="conform">
     <button (click)="clicked(i)" class="btn btn-primary">JOIN RIDE</button>
     <div  class="dialogBoxStyle" *ngIf="showIndex===i">
         <p>Your Pickup Time:</p>
         <p>8:30AM </p>
         <p>
            <button (click)="cancel()">cancel</button>
             <button>confirm</button>
         </p>
     </div>
 </div>
```

This is component .ts file

```
public showDialog:boolean = false;
public showIndex:number;

clicked(i:any) {
    this.showDialog = true;
    this.showIndex = i;
}
```

By default when page is loaded popup is in open stage its need to be  hidden stage unless until i click it.
I tried using

```
ngIf="showIndex === i && showDialog"
```

But its not working.

Comment: what is i here ?

Comment: What does "its not working" mean exactly? Add `<div>{{showIndex === i}}</div><div>{{showIndex == i}}</div><div>{{!!showDialog}}</div>` to your comopnents template outside the element with the `*ngIf="..."` and check what it shows.

Comment: `i` is the mystery here , can you give more code of HTML

Comment: i is index which shows popup for particular div only

Comment: have any jsfiddle ?

Comment: @NikhilaKanumuri U meant to hide the the div when u click clicked()?

Comment: I meant to show the popup when i click on the button but by default the popup is in open stage when page is loaded

Comment: please open your console check for the error , your code is perfectly working, there is some other issue.

Will you please share the code of html from where i is coming?

Comment: https://embed.plnkr.co/8PypLpWxYABmeJVqAXTL/ check this link when i click on button i want only particular popup to get displayed not every popup